# Create and Join Game Not Available While in Lobby

Tags: starcraft-2

I have just downloaded the "Try it" version of Starcraft II and I am attempting to create (or join) a custom game however both the Join Game and Crate Game buttons are grayed out with a hoverbox saying "Game not available while in lobby"

[image: Not available while in a lobby]

I honestly have no idea how this game works but as far as I can tell, I haven't joined any lobbies and all I have done is click the custom match button. I have waited and waited and still the buttons are grayed out.

I was thinking that maybe Battle.net needs to sync my profile or something along the lines of that however my internet isn't that bad and there are no indications to let me know if this is happening.

I have restarted the game and again waited a while but this just keeps happening. I was looking to create a custom game and play against some bots before even attempting PvP.
Any ideas on this situation? Thanks in advance for any help that is provided.

Additional Information: This is also happening when attempting to join a matchmade game (vs A.I). After restarting the game several times, it seems to sort its self out but it will eventually revert back to "Not available while in a lobby" and I have to restart several times again.

Comment: There are [some restrictions on the starter edition](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/starcraft-ii-starter-edition-and-guest-pass) but as long as you're trying to join an eligible map this shouldn't happen.  Versus AI should be working too.

Comment: Yeah I know there are restrictions but versing AI shouldn't be an issue. After trying several times and restarting the game, it appears to work but then after the game ends or I restart the game, the issue re-appears. I am now assuming this is a bug or something but if anyone has any more details, please let me know.

Comment: I would suggest contacting Blizzard technical support.  All the info I could find on this was that it happened occasionally to some people and there was no agreed-upon solution.